# Problems with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am developing an application with react native and when I run the app
I get this error.
I have the following JavaScript file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Video from 'react-native-video';

const EldenRing = () => {
  return (
    <Video
      source={(require = '../../../videos/EldenRing.mp4')}
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-native/no-inline-styles
      style={{width: '100%', height: 300}}
      controls={true}
      resizeMode={'cover'}
    />
  );
};

export default EldenRing;
```

And I want to import it in the following js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Home from '../pantallas/Home';
import ImageAccion from '../listImagenes/ImageAccion';
import EldenRing from '../listVideos/Accion/EldenRing';
import EvilDead from '../listVideos/Accion/EvilDead';
import FarCry from '../listVideos/Accion/FarCry';
import GodOfWar from '../listVideos/Accion/GodOfWar';
import Horizon from '../listVideos/Accion/Horizon';
import ImageEstrategia from '../listImagenes/ImageEstrategia';
import Age from '../listVideos/Estrategia/Age';
import Atom from '../listVideos/Estrategia/Atom';
import Black from '../listVideos/Estrategia/Black';
import Caesar from '../listVideos/Estrategia/Caesar';
import Civilization from '../listVideos/Estrategia/Civilization';
import ImageArcade from '../listImagenes/ImageArcade';
import Donkey from '../listVideos/Arcade/Donkey';
import Metal from '../listVideos/Arcade/Metal';
import Out from '../listVideos/Arcade/Out';
import Space from '../listVideos/Arcade/Space';
import Tetris from '../listVideos/Arcade/Tetris';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const StackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Juegos">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Juegos"
        component={Home}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ImAccion"
        component={ImageAccion}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="EldenRing"
        component={EldenRing}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="EvilDead"
        component={EvilDead}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="FarCry"
        component={FarCry}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="GodOfWar"
        component={GodOfWar}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Horizon"
        component={Horizon}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ImEstrategia"
        component={ImageEstrategia}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Age" component={Age} options={{headerShown: false}} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Atom"
        component={Atom}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Black"
        component={Black}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Caesar"
        component={Caesar}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Civilization"
        component={Civilization}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ImArcade"
        component={ImageArcade}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Donkey"
        component={Donkey}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Metal"
        component={Metal}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Out" component={Out} options={{headerShown: false}} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Space"
        component={Space}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Tetris"
        component={Tetris}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default StackNavigator;
```

When running it with npm start and npm run android I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ../listVideos/Accion/EldenRing from /src/navigation/StackNavigator.js: 
None of these files exist:
- src/listVideos/Accion/EldenRing(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
- src/listVideos/Accion/EldenRing/index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
```

I have tried to make several changes, but the same error keeps occurring.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your `require` is wrong, try to change by this way

```js
...
 <Video
      source={require('../../../videos/EldenRing.mp4')}
...
```

Comment: I changed that but it still gives me the error

Comment: can you show your error? maybe this path is incorrect